# POCO WebSocket - sending data from another class

Tags: c++, websocket, poco-libraries

I'm trying to create a WebSocket Server.

I can establish a connection and everything works fine so far.

In [this](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Net/samples/WebSocketServer/src/WebSocketServer.cpp) GitHub example the data is send within the `handleRequest()` method that is called when a client connects.

But can I send data to the client from another class using the established WebSocket connection?

How can I archieve this? Is this even possible?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to be more specific than "it's not working".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, of course, possible. In the example you referred, you should have a member pointer to `WebSocket` in the `RequestHandlerFactory`, eg.:

```
class RequestHandlerFactory: public HTTPRequestHandlerFactory
{
//...
private:
  shared_ptr<WebSocket> _pwebSocket;
};
```

pass it to the `WebSocketRequestHandler` [constructor](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Net/samples/WebSocketServer/src/WebSocketServer.cpp#L167):

```
return new WebSocketRequestHandler(_pwebSocket);
```

and `WebSocketRequestHandler` should look like this:

```
class WebSocketRequestHandler: public HTTPRequestHandler
{
public:
  WebSocketRequestHandler(shared_ptr<WebSocket> pWebSocket) :_pWebSocket(pWebSocket)
  {}
  void handleRequest(HTTPServerRequest& request, HTTPServerResponse& response)
  {
    // ...
    _pWebSocket.reset(make_shared<WebSocket>(request, response));
    // ...
  }
private:
  shared_ptr<WebSocket> _pWebSocket;
}
```

Now, after the request handler creates it, you will have a pointer to the WebSocket in the factory (which is long lived, unlike `RequestHandler`, which comes and goes away with every request). Keep in mind that handler executes in its own thread, so you should have some kind of locking or notification mechanism to signal when the WebSocket has actually been created by the handler (bool cast of `_pWebSocket` will be true after WebSocket was successfully created).

The above example only illustrates the case with a single WebSocket - if you want to have multiple ones, you should have an array or vector of pointers and add/remove them as needed. In any case, the WebSocket pointer(s) need not necessarily reside in the factory - you can either (a) put them elsewhere in your application and propagate them to the factory/handler or (b) have a global facility (with proper multi-thread-access mechanism) holding the WebSocket(s).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: what can a `proper multi-thread-access mechanism` for (b) look like? Just locking `sendFrame()`?

Comment: Depends on your application, of which I don't know enough to give valid advice.

Comment: In case I have several client connected over WebSocket and the members are stored in one handler. So is it enough if I just lock the `mutex` before sending data to the client?

Comment: The first thing is, you don't want to start using the socket before it is created and ready to be used (this will happen in the handler thread). If you are sending frames through one socket from multiple threads, yes - you should make sure one thread at a time is sending (somewhat unusual design, though). I do not understand the "stored in one handler" part - as explained, if you are only storing WebSocket in the handler, ti won't live very long and there's no way to access it from elsewhere (which was the original reason to ask the question).

Comment: Is this line correct? _pWebSocket.reset(make_shared<WebSocket>(request, response)); It gives compiler errors.  If I instead use assignment  everything compiles, but pwebSocket in RequestHandlerFactory is';t created when checking with if (pwebSocket)